# If $[(p\rightarrow\ q)\land (\lnot p \rightarrow \lnot r)]\rightarrow (\lnot q \rightarrow r)$ is false how to find its equivalent in other words?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

The problem is as follows:

Assume the statement which is written below is false,

```
If Gaston drinks milk then he takes his vitamins, and if he 
doesn't drink milk then he doesn't eat; therefore if Gaston 
doesn't take his vitamins, then he eats.
```

Find which of the statements in the alternatives is true.

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\textrm{Gaston drinks milk}\\
2.&\textrm{Gaston takes his vitamins}\\
3.&\textrm{Gaston eats}\\
4.&\textrm{Gaston eats or he doesn't drink milk}\\
\end{array}$

How exactly should I match the right one here?.

What I did in my attempt to solve this problem was to formulate the complex statement into terms of propositional logic as follows:

$\textrm{Gaston drinks milk = p}$

$\textrm{he takes his vitamins = q}$

$\textrm{he does eat = r}$

Then this is reformulated as follows:

$$[(p\rightarrow\ q)\land (\lnot p \rightarrow \lnot r)]\rightarrow (\lnot q \rightarrow r)$$

But what to do from here?. How exactly can this be simplified?. Is my intepretation correct?. Can someone help me here?. Please try to be the most detailed as possible so I can understand this part.

Comment: Why did you use $p$ and $r$ to mean the same thing?

Comment: "If Gaston drinks milk then he takes his vitamins, *and* if he doesn't drink" This use of AND doesn't sound as a logical *conjunction*...

Comment: *Mathematica* gives this simplification $$(p\Rightarrow q)\land (\neg p\Rightarrow \neg s)\Rightarrow (\neg q\Rightarrow s)=p\lor q\lor s$$
Gaston does one or more of the action. Sounds wrong

Comment: @Raffaele Sorry about that, I did my best in trying to fix the errors. The problem indicates that the whole statement is false. Then I believe it would have an equivalent. I don't know if what I did corrected would improve this question?

Answer (score 1):

If you make a truth table, you’ll find that the statement is false if and only if $p,q$, and $r$ are all false. In other words, that statement is false if and only if $\neg p\land\neg q\land\neg r$ is true. Your four choices of answer are $p$, $q$, $r$, and $r\lor\neg p$. The first three are clearly false, since they contradict $\neg p\land\neg q\land\neg r$. And $\neg p\land\neg q\land\neg r$ clearly implies $\neg p$, which implies $r\lor\neg p$, so $r\lor\neg p$ is true, and the correct answer is the fourth one.

If you want to proceed algebraically, note that saying that

$$\big((p\to q)\land(\neg p\to\neg r)\big)\to(\neg q\to r)$$

is false is the same as saying that

$$\big((p\to q)\land(\neg p\to\neg r)\big)\land\neg(\neg q\to r)$$

is true. And $\neg(\neg q\to r)\equiv\neg q\land\neg r$, so we’re assuming that

$$(p\to q)\land(\neg p\to\neg r)\land\neg q\land\neg r\tag{1}$$

is true. Now $p\to q\equiv\neg p\lor q$, and

$$(\neg p\lor q)\land\neg q\equiv(\neg p\land\neg q)\lor(q\land\neg q)\equiv\neg p\land\neg q\,,$$

so $(1)$ is equivalent to

$$(\neg p\to\neg r)\land\neg p\land\neg q\land\neg r\,.\tag{2}$$

Finally, $\neg p\to\neg r\equiv p\lor\neg r$, and $(p\lor\neg r)\land\neg p\equiv\neg r\land\neg p$, so $(2)$ is equivalent to $\neg r\land\neg p\land\neg q\land\neg r$ and hence to $\neg p\land\neg q\land\neg r$.