# How to simplify $(\lnot p \rightarrow \lnot q) \land p$ and match the right statement?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

The problem is as follows:

"If Maria does not leave her house then she does not catch a cold, but Maria leaves her house" is equivalent to:

I. Maria does not leave her house.

II. It is not true that, Maria leaves her house and catches a cold.

III. Maria leaves her house.

Given these statements which of the alternatives match the right answer?

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\textrm{Only III}\\
2.&\textrm{I and II}\\
3.&\textrm{Only II}\\
4.&\textrm{II and III}\\
\end{array}$

In my attempt to solve this problem I translated the statement in these terms of propositional logic.

If Maria does not leave her house then she does not catch a cold, but Maria leaves her house

Then

$\textrm{Maria leaves her house = p}$

$\textrm{Maria catches a cold = q}$

Then:

$(\lnot p \rightarrow \lnot q) \land p$

But how to simplify this expression?. Can someone help me?. Is this the right or the appropiate way to translate what it was mentioned?.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that $r\to s$ is equivalent to $\neg r\lor s$, so you have

$$\begin{align*}
(p\lor\neg q)\land p&\equiv(p\land p)\lor(\neg q\land p)\\
&\equiv p\lor(p\land\neg q)\,.
\end{align*}$$

Can you finish it from there?

Comment: Is it absorption in the end?. Because I thought that tautology only works when it is written as this $p\lor (p\land q)\equiv p$?. Can you help me with this part please?

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell: Yes, it’s absorption: $p\lor(p\land\varphi)$ is equivalent to $p$ no matter what the expression $\varphi$ is.

Comment: Why?. How can I derivate this or prove this? Can you help me with this part?

Comment: Will this apply to let's say $p\land (p\lor\lnot q)\equiv p$? Am I right here?.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell: The easiest proof is a truth table: no matter what truth value $\varphi$ has, $p\land\varphi$ has the same truth value as $p$. And yes, the final simplification is to $p$.

Comment: Is my previous comment right?. Can you take a look?. Although a truth table could verify the absorption law I was intending to ask for a more formal approach. Can you write this please,

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell: Yes, your previous comment is correct. A truth table proof **is** formal. An algebraic proof would depend on exactly what system you’re working in, and I don’t know that.

Comment: Does that mean there isn't any way to prove $p\lor (p\land \lnot q)\equiv p$ using the other formulas from propositional calculus?

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell: No, it means what I said: I don’t know the details of your particular version of propositional calculus, so I can’t tell you how to formulate an algebraic proof in that version.

Comment: I guided myself using this [page](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Absorption_Laws_(Logic)/Conjunction_Absorbs_Disjunction/Proof_2) this is the version which seems to match the one which I'm studying. I don't know if do exists other versions hence my question. Maybe can you help me with this [question please](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3961734/if-p-rightarrow-q-land-lnot-p-rightarrow-lnot-r-rightarrow-lnot-q) it makes me sad because it has been downvoted too much and I'm still stuck..

Answer (score 0):

$a\to b$ is shorthand for $\neg a\lor b$:
$$(\neg p\to\neg q)\land p\iff(p\lor\neg q)\land p\iff (p\land p)\lor(\neg q\land p)$$
The first term may be replaced with $p\land 1$:
$$\iff(1\land p)\lor(\neg q\land p)\iff(1\lor\neg q)\land p\iff p$$
Hence alternative 1 is the correct answer.

Comment: So what you did in the last step was an absorption?. Isn't it?. I'm assuming that $1$ you had just used is $T$ -Is that form of $(1\lor \lnot q)$ another way to write a tautology?.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the intuitive way to think about what's going on.  In a world where Maria does in fact leave her house, the implication, "If Maria does not leave her house, then consequences follow" gives you no information at all.  So the only piece of actual information you have is that Maria leaves her house.